# Changing port in docker-compose.yml forward to old expose port on host

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, portforwarding

I am trying to install Wordpress via docker but I got weird forwarding port on my host.

I configured firstly docker-compose.yml to run wordpress and mysql:

```
version: '2'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    links:
      - database:mysql
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=mydbname
      - WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=ap_
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=database
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
     - 9090:80
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
     - ./wordpress:/var/www/html/
  database:
   image: mysql:latest
   environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydbname
     - MYSQL_USER=root
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
   restart: unless-stopped
   ports:
     - "3306:3306"
   volumes:
     - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
 db_data: {}
```

But I realized after that I have another independent container already running on this port `9090`

So I switch to a free expose port `7878` instead (and multiple others free port).

And when I am trying to browser my Wordpress just installed at [localhost:7878](http://localhost:7878), I am redirected at [localhost:9090](http://localhost://9090).

I tried to solve it by removing the other independent container or even stopping Docker daemon and still the browser is forwarding my port to the old one `9090`. I also tried to remove docker network but no success so far..

My configuration:

```
Host machine: 
MacBook Pro mid-2015
macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6

Docker:
docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.06.0-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        0ffa825
 Built:             Wed Jul 18 19:05:26 2018
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.0-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       0ffa825
  Built:            Wed Jul 18 19:13:46 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true

Docker-compose:
docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880f
docker-py version: 3.4.1
CPython version: 3.6.4
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
```

Comment: I launched your configuration and everything was fine.
Can you add the output of `docker ps` please?

Comment: Did you already run the installation steps of Wordpress? You might have localhost:9090 in your wp_options table as `site_url` and `home`. If your site is already configured and you have this data in your db, the best way to start from scratch is to remove the volumes with docker volume prune and start over.

Comment: Docker doesn't do tcp layer 7 port redirection, that it caused by your application running inside your container.

Comment: Just by reinstalling Docker, everything went well again. That was weird behaviour.